# Generic Decoder for Swift using a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I tried to use a generic Json Decoder for all of my models using a protrocol.

//Here the definition of the  protocol:

```
func fetch<T: Decodable>(with request: URLRequest, decode: @escaping (Decodable) -> T?, completion: @escaping (Result<T, APIError>) -> Void) {.. other Code}
```

//Here the implementation:

```
func getData(from endPoint: Endpoint, completion: @escaping (Result<ApiResponseArray<Codable>, APIError>) -> Void) {

        let request = endPoint.request

        fetch(with: request, decode: { json -> Decodable in
           guard let dataResult = json as? modelData else { return  nil }
           return dataResult
        }, completion: completion)
    }
```

ApiResponseArray gives me the error: Protocol type 'Codable' (aka 'Decodable & Encodable') cannot conform to 'Decodable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols.  But how can I implement a generic decoder and passing them different models. I think I have to modify my protocol definition but how? I would like to pass the model and then receive the decoded data for the model (in my example modelData). Its obvious that the program runs when I write:
func getData(from endPoint: Endpoint, completion: @escaping (Result, APIError>) I mean when I use the concrete Model, but I want to pass the model, so that I can use the class for different models.

Thanks,
Arnold

Comment: Read this series of articles: https://robnapier.net/start-with-a-protocol

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But perhaps can you give me also a suggestion how write the completion handler to handle generic models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A protocol cannot conform to itself, `Codable` must be a concrete type or can only be used as a generic constraint.

In your context you have to do the latter, something like this

```
func fetch<T: Decodable>(with request: URLRequest, decode: @escaping (Data) throws -> T, completion: @escaping (Result<T, APIError>) -> Void) {  }

func getData<T: Decodable>(_ : T.Type = T.self, from endPoint: Endpoint, completion: @escaping (Result<T, APIError>) -> Void) {

    let request = endPoint.request

    fetch(with: request, decode: { data -> T  in
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    }, completion: completion)
}
```

A network request usually returns `Data` which is more reasonable as parameter type of the `decode` closure

Comment: A trick I just learned that makes this a lot nicer: make the first parameter of `getData()` be `_: T.Type = T.self`. That way you can pass the type in the function signature rather than having to include it in the closure (which is often a bit ugly). But if it's easy to infer, you don't have to pass it.

Comment: @RobNapier Sounds nice indeed. And how do you use the function to infer the type?

Comment: If you're passing a literal closure, then you would call it `getData(Something.self, from: endpoint) { ... })`, and you don't need to put the type in the closure. If you're passing a closure variable (so the type is known), you could just call `getData(from: endpoint, completion: completion)`.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to you how to use `Decodable` with your API call structure by using `Alamofire`.

I have created `RequestManager` class which inherits from `SessionManager` and added request call inside which common to all.

```
class RequestManager: SessionManager {

    // Create shared instance
    static let shared = RequestManager()

    // Create http headers
    lazy var httpHeaders : HTTPHeaders = {
        var httpHeader = HTTPHeaders()
        httpHeader["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        httpHeader["Accept"] = "application/json"
        return httpHeader
    }()


    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK:-
    // MARK:- Request Methods
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func responseRequest(_ url: String, method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameter: Parameters? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding, header: HTTPHeaders? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DefaultDataResponse) -> Void) -> Void {

        self.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameter, encoding: encoding, headers: header).response { response in
            completionHandler(response)
        }
    }
}
```

Then after one more class created `NetworkManager` class which hold required get/post method call and decode json by `JSONDecoder` as follow:

```
class NetworkManager {

    static let shared                   = NetworkManager()
    var progressVC                      : ProgressVC?

    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK:-
    // MARK:- Get Request Method
    //----------------------------------------------------------------

    func getResponse<T: Decodable>(_ url: String, parameter: Parameters? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default, header: HTTPHeaders? = nil, showHUD: HUDFlag = .show, message: String? = "Please wait...", decodingType: T.Type, completion: @escaping (Decodable?, APIError?) -> Void) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.showHideHud(showHUD: showHUD, message: "")
        }

        RequestManager.shared.responseRequest(url, method: .get, parameter: parameter, encoding: encoding, header: header) { response in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.showHideHud(showHUD: .hide, message: "")
            }

            guard let httpResponse = response.response else {
                completion(nil, .requestFailed("Request Failed"))
                return
            }

            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                if let data = response.data {
                    do {
                        let genericModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(decodingType, from: data)
                        completion(genericModel, nil)
                    } catch {

                        do {

                            let error = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]

                            if let message = error!["message"] as? String {

                                completion(nil, .errorMessage(message)!)

                            } else if let message = error!["message"] as? Int {

                                completion(nil, .errorMessage(String(describing: "Bad Request = \(message)")))
                            }

                        } catch {
                            completion(nil, .jsonConversionFailure("JSON Conversion Failure"))
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    completion(nil, .invalidData("Invalid Data"))
                }
            } else {
                completion(nil, .responseUnsuccessful("Response Unsuccessful"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*`ProgressVC` is my custom class to show progress view when api call.*

After that, I have created `DataManager` class which will help me to create request url.

```
class DataManager: NSObject {

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK:- Variables
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    static let shared   = DataManager()
    let baseUrl         = WebServiceURL.local    


    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK:- Custom Methods
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Get API url with endpoints
    func getURL(_ endpoint: WSEndPoints) -> String {
        return baseUrl + endpoint.rawValue
    }
}
```

I have created following enum to send data or error in my completion block.

```
enum Result<T, U> where U: Error  {
    case success(T)
    case failure(U)
}
```

Here is list of error which stored custom message related to status fired during api call.

```
enum APIError: Error {
    case errorMessage(String)
    case requestFailed(String)
    case jsonConversionFailure(String)
    case invalidData(String)
    case responseUnsuccessful(String)
    case jsonParsingFailure(String)

    var localizedDescription: String {

        switch self {

        case.errorMessage(let msg):
            return msg

        case .requestFailed(let msg):
            return msg

        case .jsonConversionFailure(let msg):
            return msg

        case .invalidData(let msg):
            return msg

        case .responseUnsuccessful(let msg):
            return msg

        case .jsonParsingFailure(let msg):
            return msg
        }
    }
}
```

Then after, I will extend this `DataManager` class to call web service based on module. So I will create Swift file and extend `DataManager` class and call relative API.

See following, In API call I will return relative model into `Result` like `Result<StoreListModel, APIError>`

```
extension DataManager {

    // MARK:- Store List
    func getStoreList(completion: @escaping (Result<StoreListModel, APIError>) -> Void) {

        NetworkManager.shared.getResponse(getURL(.storeList), parameter: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, header: getHeaders("bd_suvlascentralpos"), showHUD: .show, message: "Please wait...", decodingType: StoreListModel.self) { (decodableData, apiError) in

            if apiError != nil {

                completion(.failure(apiError!))

            } else {

                guard let userData = decodableData as? StoreListModel else {
                    completion(.failure(apiError!))
                    return
                }

                completion(.success(userData))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From completion block of request I will get decodable data which here safely type cast.

**Use:**

```
DataManager.shared.getStoreList { (result) in

        switch result {

        case .success(let storeListModel):

            if let storeList = storeListModel, storeList.count > 0 {
                self.arrStoreList = storeList

                self.tblStoreList.isHidden = false
                self.labelEmptyData.isHidden = true

                self.tblStoreList.reloadData()
            } else {
                self.tblStoreList.isHidden = true
                self.labelEmptyData.isHidden = false
            }
            break

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            break
        }
    }
```

**Note:-** Some variables, models classes are my custom. You can replace it with your.